# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier (Chrome extension)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm getting an Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier on the first line for this snippet of code. I'm new to JavaScript so it's probably something very simple that I'm missing.

```
chrome.tabs.getSelected(function(Tab tab) {
    var url = tab.url;
    console.log(url);
});
console.log("test");
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
chrome.tabs.getSelected(function(Tab tab) {
```

JavaScript doesn't have static type declarations; when the Chrome docs tell you `Tab tab` that's just for your information, not what you'd actually write in JS.

Also you're missing an argument to the `getSelected` method.

```
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
```